# auto scaling and load balancing Spring boot restful service

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, load-balancing, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring boot RESTful service endpoint. this service should be available on port:8080 always. but when too many HTTP requests arrive, I want it to be scaled up automatically. and also scale down if number of requests falls down. for scaling up/down, I have no problem, because I can use Spring Cloud Eureka + Jenkins. but the problem is that, they create service instances with different port numbers (obviously). but I need somehow to mask the whole scaling up thing from clients. because they should only use the port 8080. so I am confused, how I can load balance the requests on port 8080 to my multiple instances, which are running on other different ports. appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: That is typically what a api gateway or router is for (zuul, spring cloud gateway, haproxy, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Use zuul routing to load balance your instances.